# jquery click for css image based hover?

Tags: jquery, css, image, hover, click

I have a page where the use of `.button` will be used as virtual button. Once clicked it'll shift the background image to do it's "hover animation".

However the code I got doesn't seem to want to do anything, and no errors listed.

```
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '-468px 0').delay(200).css('background-position', '0 0');
    });
```

I also tried

```
    $(".button").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '-468px 0').delay(200).css('background-position', '0 0');
        });
    });
```

And also tried

```
    $(".button").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "-468px 0"}, 100);
        });
    });
```

CSS

```
.button {
    color: #4e5645;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #b3c799;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 120px;
    width: 468px;
    line-height: 120px;
    background: url(button_hover.png) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;    
}
```

HTML

```
            <div class="buttonc">
                <div class="button">TAX PEOPLE</div>
            </div>
```

Any ideas? Yes, jQuery core is correctly linked and used for other features.

Edit: Alternatively to the solution below, I found this out today on my own writing casually... Funny how I didn't think of it last night for the hover button. Wow.

```
    $(".rightctext").click(function(){
        var div = $(this);
        div.css('text-shadow', '0px 0px 20px #fbf5df');
        setTimeout(function(){
            div.css('text-shadow', '0px 0px 10px #474333');
        }, 200);
    });
```

Comment: and what about your Html and css code, can u share it ?

Comment: I suppose not sure how that implies to the javascript aspect. You just use a name to call it, and CSS shouldn't interfere. One second.

Comment: Looks like I forgot to declare pixels in my JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delay is only valid with animations, .css changes instantly. Instead you can use the [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) callback function executed after the animation has completed. I think this is what you are after:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
     $(this).animate({'background-position-x': '-468px'},200, function(){
         $(this).animate({'background-position-x': '0px'},200);
     });   
 });
```

EDIT:
No animation:

```
 $(".button").click(function(){
     $(this).animate({'background-position-x': '-468px'},0).delay(200).animate(
         {'background-position-x': '0px'},0);   
 });
```

Edit by Jordan:

Alternate method I discovered casually as if I never had this problem last night... Wonders what sleep can do. Thanks for the help again everyone.

```
    $(".button").click(function(){
        var div = $(this);
        div.css('background-position-x', '-468px');
        var end = setTimeout(function(){
            div.css('background-position-x', '0px');
            clearTimeout(end);
        }, 200);
    });
```

Comment: That's a good fix, as it works, but I noticed it scrolls the image, instead of instantly changing like it needs to (it's one image that is a button one less colorful, one colorful.) I have been looking at `toggleClass` but I'm trying to figure out how to correctly remove the added class after a short time after the click.

Comment: You can use delay if your using animate. You original code worked except for the delay part. It was just changing css and then changing back instantly so it looked like it wasn't doing anything. Try my edit.

Comment: By golly gee! you did it! I'm trying to see what has changed in the other code to make it snap like it should.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to put "px".

```
$(this).css('background-position', '-468px 0px').delay(200).css('background-position', '0px 0px');
```

Comment: Yep just noticed. Added, no go still. "0" and "0px" interpret the same.